# What happened to radha when she grew up?

Tags: krishna, radha

My question concerns radha, the companion of Krishna. I have heard that Krishna and radha were companions since childhood. But I want to know what happened to her when she grew up. Thank you

Comment: The character of Radha is of dubious origins.. She appeared herself debatablely first in Geeta-Govinda (a word of great devotional rasa) to bring out the romantic/loving aspect of Krsna. see http://www.manuscripts.qtanalytics.com/Admin/Notes/VEETHIKA635943724398631224.pdf

Answer (score 2):

> Krishna and Radha are eternal consorts as per texts. They live
>   eternally in their abode called Goloka Vrindavan and it is said the
>   goal of a person's life is to be part of that planet.
>
> Krishna and Radha represent 100% pure unconditional love and are
>   famously referred to as the "all attractive couple". Radha Rani is
>   spoken very less in all scriptures and texts because she is the most
>   precious person. Krishna chases her and she represents
>   bhakti/devotion, so in other words it is implied that Krishna chases
>   devotion. So she is a well kept secret of Krishna.
>
> When they descended to Earth they were born in the same village and
>   played pastimes and loved each other 100%. The whole leela of Krishna
>   going away to defeat Kamsa, is to show that aspect of love during
>   separation, in this case, a very long separation. Radha Rani
>   understands this and decides to experience the sweet nectar of longing
>   for her love during separation. This is another aspect of the 100%
>   love situation - something which will never happen in the material
>   world. Radha Rani loves him despite whatever happens with him and
>   Krishna loves her back equally. They both enjoy aching for each other
>   under separation. They cry, they feel lost, they undergo all these
>   arduous feelings just to test their love time and again.
>
> Meanwhile Radharani marries a dumb Yadava called Abhimanyu and has
>   quite some bad encounters with her in-laws. But being Radharani she
>   takes it in her stride very well.
>
> Jatila-devi is Radharani's mother-in-law and Abhimanyu is Radharani's
>   so-called husband. Kutila-devi, who is always eager to find fault, is
>   Radharani's sister-in-law.

[Source](http://www.vrindavan.de/radha.htm)

> Abhimanyu does not realize the value of the diamond he has with him.
>   Krishna anyway does not care, neither does Radha. They both only have
>   eyes for each other. There is a pastime where Radharani is in her room
>   and Krishna is being transported inside a basket full of flowers by
>   her Gopi friends into her room and they spend the night in peace -
>   this is after Radharani's marriage.
>
> There is no problem for Radharani to survive because she represents
>   100% Hladini energy aka pleasure potency of Krishna. So she can be
>   ever smiling and ever caring always in his remembrance. Krishna when
>   he marries Rukmini, Satyabhama and other wives, he does it in the
>   Visnu duty form. But the highest of all is Radharani in his heart.
>   Others are all by association with Visnu duty form. There is also
>   another story where Rukmini repeatedly questions Krishna as to why he
>   keeps exclaiming Radhe Radhe in his dreams.

**Interesting stuff**

> They also say the only way to get into Krishna's heart is to please
>   Radha. That is why people say "Radhe Krishna" and also say that a
>   Krishna idol without Radha is incomplete. In the Srimad Bhagavatam,
>   Sukhdev Goswami who is Vyasa's son is actually the eternal pet parrot
>   of Radharani who is watching the love between Krishna and Radha non
>   stop. That love is 100% pure love and hence Sukhdev Goswami only
>   mentions Radha in the Srimad Bhagavatam, but without taking her name.
>   If he takes her name, he gets into the trance of transcendental
>   ecstasy which he won't be able to come out of. She is referred to as
>   the principal gopi.

- anayaradhita nunam bhagavan hariir isvarah
- yan no vihaya govindah prito yam anayad rahah

[Source](http://backtobhakti.com/sri-radha%E2%80%99s-name-in-srimad-bhagavatam/)

> They also say there is something much higher and more sweeter than the
>   politics of Mahabharatha and that is Krishna's life with Radha in
>   Vrndavan.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many speculations as to what happened to her, since she disappears quiet abruptly after lord Krishna's childhood saga, where she played a very pivotal role.

So she remains a mystery yet till now with nothing definite to settle for, so I will be giving you 2 accounts of what have I come across about her :

[Theory 1](https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-Radha-after-Krishna-moved-to-dwarka-What-were-highlights-of-her-later-life/answer/Priya-Ananthasankar?srid=wT9M&share=86dee1ba)
And 
[Theory 2](https://www.quora.com/What-happened-to-Radha-after-Krishna-moved-to-dwarka-What-were-highlights-of-her-later-life/answer/Anup-Jalan?srid=wT9M&share=8d675c96)

Comment: ArnavDas - The citing of source should be from authentic scriptures like "Mahabharat"  Or Shree Bhagvat puran. One should avoid giving reference from other question answer sites like in your case.

Comment: Arnav--Theor  2  by anup jalan  he himself has given master of none--How this answer fits?

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan Oh that's "jack of many master of none" is just a cheesy tagline, for himself...

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Actually I tried to trace some authentic source regarding this issue, online, unfortunately I didn't find any.....so I gave a link to 2 such accounts to which only I knew of...

Comment: @Arnav--that cheesy tag revealed about  himself   master of none---

Comment: Arnav Das : Please refer [this meta answer](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/597/3500) to know valid sources.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [Was Radha aunt of Krishna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31795/was-radha-aunt-of-krishna/31808#31808) post, Radha was elder to Krishna and her shadow was already married to Yashoda's brother Raayana and real Radha was companion of Krishna.

As per [Brahmavaivarta Purana: Prakrti-Khandam: Chapter 49. Pronouncing of curse mutually by Radha and Sudama](https://archive.org/details/BrahmavaivartaPuranaWithEnglishTranslationVolume1/page/n477):

> 46 In the sacred forest of Vrndavana in the land of Bharata, Krsna the lord of the cowherds enjoyed the company of Radha in Vrndavana for a short duration.
>
> 47 Thereafter because of the curse 
>   of Sudama both of them were separated from 
>   each other.
>
> 48 After the lapse of a hundred years, both Krsna 
>   and Radha met each other while on a pilgrimage.
>
> 49 Thereafter lord Krsna who was well-versed 
>   the knowledge of tattva went back to Goloka 
>   together with Radhika and her mother named 
>   Kalavatl, besides all the cowherdesses and 
>   Yasodha the mother of Krsna.
>
> 50 Vrsabhanu, Nanda, all the cowherds and 
>   cowherdesses who had arrived on earth from the 
>   Goloka went back to their abode.